# ... в параметрах шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

В чём разница между следующими объявлениями? Как правильно вызывать оба варианта?

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T...);

template<typename... T>
void foo(T...);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первый вариант эквивалентен

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T, ...);
```

то есть первый параметр функции имеет тип `T` (шаблонный параметр), а остальные параметры - это классические унаследованные из языка C переменные параметры, доступ к которым осуществляется через `va_list` и макросы из `<stdarg.h>`. С++, однако, разрешает не ставить запятую перед `...`, что и делает ваш первый вариант корректным.

Второй вариант

```
template<typename... T>
void foo(T...);
```

это появившийся в С++11 шаблонный параметр pack.

Вызывать оба варианта можно одинаково - указывайте аргументы и все. Разница только в том, что первый вариант требует хотя бы одного аргумента, а второй вариант может быть вызван вообще без аргументов. Также в С++ значения не всех типов разрешается передавать как аргументы для `...` параметров в первом варианте.

P.S. Оба варианта синтаксиса можно скомбинировать в одном объявлении, получив необычно выглядящее

```
template<typename... T>
void foo(T......);
```

---

Если обе функции видны одновременно, то основные правила overload resolution, которые работают в таких случаях, это

1. Преобразование аргумента к параметру `...` (ellipsis conversion sequence) обладает наименьшим рангом, т.е. является наименее предпочтительным, по сравнению с другими преобразованиями.
2. Шаблонная функция с "конкретным" шаблонным параметром является *более специализированной* и более предпочтительной, чем функция с параметром, полученным из parameter pack.

По этим правилам, например, вызов `foo(1)` вызовет первый вариант (работает правило  2), а вызов `foo(1, 2)` вызовет второй вариант(работает правило 1).