# Неоднозначный вызов шаблонных функций

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void foo(T...) {std::cout << 'A';}

template<typename... T>
void foo(T...) {std::cout << 'B';}

int main() {
  foo(1);   // prints A
  foo(1,2); // prints B
}
```

Как правильно вызывать каждую из функций? Почему в первом случае вызывается первая функция, а во втором - вторая?

Comment: вопрос связан с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/910854/317064) вопросом

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правила overload resolution в полном объеме довольно сложны, но в таких случаях работают в основном следующие правила

1. Преобразование аргумента к параметру `...` (ellipsis conversion sequence) обладает *наименьшим рангом*, т.е. является наименее предпочтительным по сравнению с другими преобразованиями.
2. Шаблонная функция с "конкретным" шаблонным параметром `typename T` является *более специализированной* и более предпочтительной, чем функция с параметром, полученным из parameter pack `typename... T`.

По эти правилам, например, вызов `foo(1)` вообще никак не вовлекает в рассмотрение параметры `...` первого варианта. То есть решение принимается только на основе одного аргумента. Первый вариант выигрывает по правилу 2.

Вызов `foo(1, 2)` в первом варианте требует ellipsis conversion sequence для преобразования аргумента `2` к параметру `...`. Во втором варианте ничего подобного не требуется. По правилу 1 вызывается второй вариант.